# PHP - get value from database and display known value

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I've been searching for this for a while now.. It's probably very simple but I just can't seem to get it right.

My website uses a file with translations. Every translation has it's own variable.
Like: `$_text_login` (which translates to: Login or Aanmelden or Derp).

I've made a menu table within my database. One of the menu items has the text: `$_text_login`

Obviously, when I get the menu information, it doesn't show the currently set value of the variable, it just shows `$_text_login`.

I've tried [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) but that doesn't work..

Can anyone help?

Comment: if $_text_login is a variable and you want to render the string it contains, you'll need to echo it out. Example:  <?=$_text_login;?>

Comment: so basically you need help getting your template system working?

Comment: If you're having to resort to `eval()` or *variable variable* hacks to get this to work, it kind of implies, to me anyway, that you're doing something very odd (or wrong). I'd probably go back to the drawing board on this one if I were you and rethink it.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend this approach and I would santize the variable name, but from the sounds of it, you could achieve what you are saying with:

```
echo eval('return '. $item  . ';');
```

Where $item would be the result from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say `$row` is the result you received from the database, and `text` is the name of the column containing the variable.
Then you would do this:

```
echo $$row['text'];
```

If `$row['text']` is `_text_login` this should output the value of `$_text_login`.
You should not have the $ in the database.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation of PHP you can just use `$$varname` structure: I mean:

```
<?php
$fruit = "apple";
$variable = "fruit";

print_r($$variable); //outputs apple
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Thanks..

Eval did work eventually.. Because I matched the actual variables...
I feel stupid now..

while($main_obj = $query_mainmenuitems->fetch_object()) {

```
            if (preg_match('/\$text_/',$main_obj->value)) {
                $mainmenu_title = eval('return '.$main_obj->value.';');
            } else {
                $mainmenu_title = $main_obj->value;
            }
```

}

It shouldn't be $_text_logon .. all my translations have $text_[whatever]